# ERROR JAVA CODE correct it

Tags: java, class, enums

```
//my code is on java code on employ details using console
//my input is no.of employess
//i am taking input a employ details
//function on searching for a given employ for a given id
```

// code meaning
    // #String employee[][]=new String[numberOfEmployees][12];  will store //employ details
//#String input will take the employee  details in the string formatt.

## //#String choice will take choice as yes to search the another employee

## /*ABOVE CODE IS ON DEVELOPING SIMPLE JAVA CODE ON EMPLOY MANAGEMENT SYSTEM*/

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class EmployeeManagement {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner read=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter  the no.of employees");
        int numberOfEmployees=read.nextInt();//GIVEN INPUT FOR NO.OF EMPLOYESS
        int employeeId;
        String employee[][]=new String[numberOfEmployees][12];
        for(int inner=0;inner<numberOfEmployees;inner++){/*taken input on employ details*/
            for(int outer=0;outer<11;outer++){
                employee[inner][outer]=read.nextLine();
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        for(int inner=0;inner<numberOfEmployees;inner++){
                 employee[inner][11] = (int)(Integer.parseInt(employee[inner][5])+Integer.parseInt(employee[inner][6])
                                 +Integer.parseInt(employee[inner][7])+Integer.parseInt(employee[inner][8])
                                 -Integer.parseInt(employee[inner][9])-Integer.parseInt(employee[inner][10]));
                           }
        String choice;


                     do{
            System.out.println("do you want to search enter employee id");
            String input=read.nextLine();
            System.out.println("do you want to continue press yes or YES");
                        read.nextLine();
            choice =read.nextLine();        
        }while(choice=="yes" || choice=="YES");
                     for(int inner=0;inner<numberOfEmployees;inner++){
            if(employee[inner][0]=="input"){   
        for(int outer=0;outer<12;outer++)
            System.out.print(employee[inner][outer]);
                                                               }
        System.out.println();







         }



    }
}
```

Comment: a) format the code properly b) ask the question clearly

Comment: This is one angry question. Please avoid using ALL CAPS *especially* when you're making it **SUPER BIG AND BOLD**.

Answer (score 0):

If you format the code in the question properly it will be easier to see what's going wrong. But to start with:

Don't compare Strings like this:

```
choice=="yes"
```

Then you just check if the first String object is the same object as the second one, and in this case they never are.

Instead, go like this:

```
choice.equals("yes")
```

Or better yet, since you never risk a NullPointerException:

```
"yes".equals(choice)
```